# Break Line Table vertical pdfmake.js

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I want to create a dynamic table with tables inside each cell with pdfmake.js
The problem is that i can not figure out how to automatically make a line break when the table reaches the end of the page vertically.

For example:

```
var dd = {
          pageOrientation: "landscape",
          content: [{table: {
                        body: [
                               [
                                {tableObj},{tableObj},{tableObj}....
                               ]
                              ]
                             }
                      }
                     ]
              }
```

Is there a way to get a line break inside the body?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried "pageBreakBefore"?

Comment: Yes i have. But it does not break the table.